# Why do LTE Network Interfaces Change Names?

Tags: networking, mobile-network

You may have seen my earlier question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236082/rooted-phone-using-wifi-and-lte-simultaneously) detailing my struggles with multiplexing LTE and WiFi on a rooted Android device. Much of this stems from an issue I seem to run into with the LTE network interfaces used by my device (Google Pixel 4a), namely v4-rmnet_data{$X} where $X is some number from 0-9. When I do an ip link show, I can see many LTE interfaces formatted rmnet_data{$X} but only one formatted like v4-rmnet_data{$X}. I'm assuming this v4 interface is an IPv4 link generated from one of these IPv6 links. Occasionally, I will see that the $X used by the v4 link has changed inexplicably. I can't seem to find a good explanation as to why this happens. One second, the active link is v4-rmnet_data0, the next it is v4-rmnet_data2 and the v4-rmnet_data0 link has ceased to exist. Does anyone know what causes this to occur? Is there anything I can do to prevent it from happening? Since I am manually changing routing tables, disruptions like these cause disaster.

Thanks for your help!